# Is ordering of names possible in Fluent dashboard?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I have implemented fluent dashboard in my website's admin side. But the ordering of displaying the names of models is not according to my wish. For eg:
 In Administration section, it is displaying the models in this order:
1)Groups  2) Users 3)Sites 4)Footer Settings 5)Website Settings.

But i want to display it in the dashboard in this order:
1)Website Settings  2) Users 3)Footer Settings 4)Sites 5)Groups. 
 I tried a lot replacing the models with one another, but of no use. I seek your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into [django Snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1939/#comments).
follow process as explained.

```
ADMIN_REORDER = (
    ('app1', ('App1Model1', 'App1Model2', 'App1Model3')),
    ('app2', ('App2Model1', 'App2Model2')),
)
```